# Are there any clues whether multiple down votes are from the same source?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Yesterday I received 4 down votes across 4 different answers all within about a minute and a half. This stands out to me only because all 4 answers were recent, with +1 score originally and no down votes (and each was answered on a different day).

As you can see from my profile, I'm no stranger to using down (or up) votes myself, so I am not here complaining it's unfair (etc.), and I know this is an insignificant number but that's why it made me wonder (because even it it were by the same user, it probably wasn't enough to trigger reversal)

When this happens (because everyone experiences this some days) **are there any clues to tell you whether they might be serial down votes by the same user?** (vs deserved votes from the larger community)

*To be completely clear, I don't want to know who voted - I'm wondering whether there is a way to know that it is multiple people vs one person (without flagging and wasting a moderators time for 8rep)*

For example: Can you use Stack Exchange Data Explorer to see the count of unique voters for a set of questions?

[image: rep tab]

Comment: votes are anonymous so I doubt anything could be done

Comment: You have two powerful weapons at your disposal: your intuition and your judgement. If you can look at your rep history objectively, you are in the best position to make the most out of them. If you *can't*, best not to pick them up in case you misfire. Can't say much other than that.

Comment: Good comment. My intuition is saying it likely is revenge, giving the questions targeted. Although I can't say who, or why they felt the need.

I don't consider this duplicate - I want to know for example can you use Stack Exchange data explorer to see the count of unique voters for a set of questions?

Comment: There's also a third indication, if they targeted *answers*, hence costing them reputation, you have a good indication that they're passionate about it. You are meaningful to them!!

Comment: @NickCardoso SEDE doesn't have that data. It doesn't have the voters, nor does it have the exact time (only the date) in the votes table.

Comment: Thanks @rene. Date would be enough to determine this, but if SEDE doesn't have anything related, then I have my answer!

Comment: I looked at this and I do suspect it was one user, due to all votes coming within a minute or two. I also think I know who it was, and have informed employees to investigate and invalidate these votes. It may take a while for them to get to the bottom of this, though.

Comment: Thanks For that @BradLarson - The rep is little but I am trying to get my Android 'score' up to get to Gold badge level, so that's useful. I was really hoping there was a way with SEDE to 'confirm suspicion' before ever wasting anyone elses time with such things